# Enable a mediawiki function to render wikitext

Tags: mediawiki

My mediawiki version is 1.16.5. I have a function that selects a random quote from the database and displays it on a wiki page. Italics and bold are rendered when I use html, however, I want to be able to use wikitext, specifically external links format, i.e.

```
[http://mediawiki.org MediaWiki]
```

Currently, if using something like the above, it is not rendered and displays literally. There is some reference on what is needed here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions#How_do_I_render_wikitext_in_my_extension.3F but I do not know how to implement this.

Here is the code:

```
function wfGetQuote() {
    $randstr = wfRandom();
    $row = selectRandomQuoteFromDB( $randstr );

    if( !$row )
        $row = selectRandomQuoteFromDB( "0" );

    if( $row ) {
        list( $quote, $attribution ) = explode( "\n", $row->quote_text );
        return '<div id="trrandomquote"><div id="trquote">'. $quote .'</div> <span>'. $attribution .'</span></div>';
    }
    else
        return 'Error: No quote found';
}

function selectRandomQuoteFromDB( $randstr ) {
    global $wgUser, $site;

    $lang = $wgUser->getOption( 'language' );
    if( $site == 'wiki' )
        $lang = 'en';

    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $use_index = $dbr->useIndexClause( 'quote_random' );
    $quote = $dbr->tableName( 'quote' );

    $sql = "SELECT quote_text
        FROM $quote $use_index
        WHERE quote_random >= $randstr
        AND quote_lang = '$lang'";

    $sql = $dbr->limitResult( $sql, 1, 0 );
    $fname = 'RandomQuote::selectRandomQuoteFromDB';
    $res = $dbr->query( $sql, $fname );
    return $dbr->fetchObject( $res );
}
```

Comment: You're not developing a tag extension, do you?

Comment: No, I just want the existing wiki mark-up to work in quotes text.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use the [$wgOut->addWikiText( $msg );](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgOut) function.

I would modify your code to:

```
function wfGetQuote() {
  global $wgOut; // Added line

  $randstr = wfRandom();
  $row = selectRandomQuoteFromDB( $randstr );

  if( !$row )
      $row = selectRandomQuoteFromDB( "0" );

  if( $row ) {
      list( $quote, $attribution ) = explode( "\n", $row->quote_text );
      $wgOut->addWikiText( '<div id="trrandomquote"><div id="trquote">'. $quote .'</div> <span>'. $attribution .'</span></div>' );
  }
  else
      return 'Error: No quote found';
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it may do the job you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but the output was not rendered. For example I got:


`<div id="trrandomquote"><div id="trquote">Quote text</div> <span>[http://www.somesite.com/index.php?topic=49027.0 Author], fragment 761</span></div>`

And this is the bit modifying the quotes text:

`foreach( $lines as $line ) {
$rand = wfRandom();
$line = preg_replace( "#<br />''#", "\n" , $line );
$line = preg_replace( "#''#", '', $line );
$line = preg_replace( "#<br /><i>#", "\n" , $line );
$line = preg_replace( "#</i>#", '', $line );
$line = $dbr->addQuotes( $line );`

Comment: Testing the output source code inside a mediawiki article did parse wikitext OK, so this corroborates that there is something missing in the function and not in the code pasted above mofidying the quotes text.

Comment: You can try by mixing `addWikiText` and `addHTMLText` functions of the `$wgOut` object. Put all the HTML markup inside the `addHTMLText` function and all the wikitext inside the `addWikiText` one.  That should do the job...

Comment: Ah, I forgot the change in the "$wgOut->addWikiText" line. I implemented that too but the quote switched place from top of article to bottom!

Comment: Using `addHTMLText` instead gave me `Call to undefined method OutputPage::addHTMLText()` Should have been `addHTML` instead which has same result as previous one: quote moves to the bottom!